# Replace Window rootViewController with another view controller using Storyboard

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I am new to Storyboard-ing, been using IB mostly. I have an initial temporary View Controller (let's call it `BootstrapViewController`) which job is solely to load data from a webservice, then hand over control to a UITabViewController. The data is required to determine what tab items to show.

In non-Storyboard world, I just do:

```
// Do whatever you need to UITabViewController, then call this
[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController = myTabVC;
```

Is this possible using Storyboard? I tried creating a named segue from BootstrapViewController to the tab view controller, then calling `performSegueWithIdentifier`, no luck.

Comment: Maybe I am approaching this wrong? Should I take `BootstrapViewController` out of the Storyboard, load it first, then manually load the MainStoryBoard?

Comment: Or put UINavigationController -> BootstrapViewController -> UITabViewController. Then call `performSegueWithIdentifier`

Answer (score 1):

You can do it exactly the same way you have always done it, by setting the window's rootViewController property.  You can even load the tab bar out of a storyboard.  Use UIStoryboard's instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: to load a particular view controller from a storyboard.